# The new object returned from Object.create() method seems overwrintg its orginal object, and it is not what I expect

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript world.
I expected the Object.create(foo) method creates a new object of the 'foo' type. But, as in the following example, the newly created object seems to have some member properties that are still referred to those of its original object. So, the new one overwrites those values of the original if the new one's are modified.

I know JavaScript is using "copy by reference", except for copying the primitives. But, as many JavaScript guides/references say, Object.create(foo) creates a new 'foo' object, every time it is called, doesn't it?

Talking about my example,

```
"using strict";
var A = {a:1, b:1, c:1};
var B = Object.create(A);

console.log("// STEP 1 ////////////////////");
B.a = 2; B.b = 2; B.c = 2;
console.log(A); // Object { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }
console.log(B); // Object { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2 }

console.log("// STEP 2 ////////////////////");
var AA = {
    _a: Object.create(A),
    _b: Object.create(B)
}
console.log("AA.a = " + AA._a.a + " : " + AA._a.b + " : " + AA._a.c); // AA.a = 1 : 1 : 1
console.log("AA.b = " + AA._b.a + " : " + AA._b.b + " : " + AA._b.c); // AA.b = 2 : 2 : 2

console.log("// STEP 3 ////////////////////");
var BB = Object.create(AA);
console.log("AA.a = " + AA._a.a + " : " + AA._a.b + " : " + AA._a.c); // AA.a = 1 : 1 : 1
console.log("AA.b = " + AA._b.a + " : " + AA._b.b + " : " + AA._b.c); // AA.b = 2 : 2 : 2
console.log("BB.a = " + BB._a.a + " : " + BB._a.b + " : " + BB._a.c); // BB.a = 1 : 1 : 1
console.log("BB.b = " + BB._b.a + " : " + BB._b.b + " : " + BB._b.c); // BB.b = 2 : 2 : 2

console.log("// STEP 4 ////////////////////");
BB._a.a = 3, BB._a.b = 3, BB._a.c = 3;
console.log("AA.a = " + AA._a.a + " : " + AA._a.b + " : " + AA._a.c); // AA.a = 3 : 3 : 3
console.log("AA.b = " + AA._b.a + " : " + AA._b.b + " : " + AA._b.c); // AA.b = 2 : 2 : 2
console.log("BB.a = " + BB._a.a + " : " + BB._a.b + " : " + BB._a.c); // BB.a = 3 : 3 : 3
console.log("BB.b = " + BB._b.a + " : " + BB._b.b + " : " + BB._b.c); // BB.b = 2 : 2 : 2
```

I have expected and understood the outputs until step 3. But, I got trouble with step 4. Why is the object BB overwriting the AA's member properties (_a.a, _a.b, and _a.c) here? Now, I really got confused with the behavior of the Object.create() method.

I am aiming the following outputs for step 4 like this:

```
BB._a.a = 3, BB._a.b = 3, BB._a.c = 3;
console.log("AA.a = " + AA._a.a + " : " + AA._a.b + " : " + AA._a.c); // AA.a = 1 : 1 : 1
console.log("AA.b = " + AA._b.a + " : " + AA._b.b + " : " + AA._b.c); // AA.b = 2 : 2 : 2
console.log("BB.a = " + BB._a.a + " : " + BB._a.b + " : " + BB._a.c); // BB.a = 3 : 3 : 3
console.log("BB.b = " + BB._b.a + " : " + BB._b.b + " : " + BB._b.c); // BB.b = 2 : 2 : 2
```

Only the place I suspect is the declarations of member _a and _b in step 2. The usage of Object.create(A) and Object.create(B) might be a cause of the problem. But I cannot convince myself or improve the situation.

What am I missing here? How should I correct the code to have my aiming result?

---------------- My additional comment starts from here ----------------

After I received a replay from @Mark Meyer (thanks!), I understand the idea of Object.create() method. But, then, how can we implement a class containing some other classes inside it in common object programming style?
For example:

```
var CPU = { name: null };
var MB = { name: null };
var PC = { cpu: Object.create(CPU), mb: Object.create(MB) };

var pc1 = Object.create(PC);
pc1.cpu.name = "Intel i7";
pc1.mb.name = "ASUS";

var pc2 = Object.create(PC);
pc2.cpu.name = "AMD ryzen",
pc2.mb.name = "GIGABYTE";

console.log("PC1 has CPU: " + pc1.cpu.name + " MB: " + pc1.mb.name); // PC1 has CPU: AMD ryzen MB: GIGABYTE
console.log("PC2 has CPU: " + pc2.cpu.name + " MB: " + pc2.mb.name); // PC2 has CPU: AMD ryzen MB: GIGABYTE
```

I now know why pc2 overwrites pc1 here. I want pc1 and pc2 to behave independent. But, I cannot come up with an alternative way to achieve my goal. Is there any way to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

`A = Object.create(B)` creates a new object `A` that is *prototype linked* it to `B`. It doesn't *copy* the properties to `A`.
This means `A` is able to access the properties on `B` if it doesn't have those properties itself. When `A` doesn't have some property it will look to see if `B` has it and use that. For example:

```js
let A = {a:1, b:1, c:1};
let B = Object.create(A)

console.log("does B have an 'a' prop?", B.hasOwnProperty('a'))
console.log("does A have an 'a' prop?", A.hasOwnProperty('a'))

console.log(B.a)  // accesses A.a because there is no B.a
A.a = 10          // changing A.a
console.log(B.a)  // is reflected here
```

When you add a property to `B` it now has it's own property and no longer needs to defer up the prototype chain:

```js
let A = {a:1, b:1, c:1};
let B = Object.create(A)
B.a = "hello"

console.log("does B have an 'a' prop?", B.hasOwnProperty('a'))
console.log("does A have an 'a' prop?", A.hasOwnProperty('a'))

console.log(B.a)  // B now has it's own a property
A.a = 10          // so changing A.a
console.log(B.a)  // doesn't change this
```

When properties point to other objects, just remember the same thing holds. Unless `B` has it's own version of that object, changes to the object on `A` will be seen when `B` access the object. And since `B` and `A` point to the same reference it's possible for `B` to make changes on the object as well and you'll see those when you look at `A`'s reference to the object:

```js
let A = {a:{test: "Object A.a"}};
let B = Object.create(A)

console.log("A.a and B.a are the same object?", A.a === B.a)

console.log(B.a)          //  B.a still points to A.a
A.a.test = "A changed"
console.log(B.a)          //  B.a still points to A.a so it sees the change

B.a.test = "B changed me" // this doens't create an `a` property on B
                          // B.a and A.a still point to the same object

console.log(A.a)          // B changed the test prop on this object

// give B it's own a property:
B.a = {test: "B's own"}
console.log("A.a and B.a are the still same object?", A.a === B.a)
```

Comment: thanks for replay! I understand the idea between Object.create() and prototype.
But, then, how can we implement a class containing other classes inside it in JavaScript? (e.g. implementing PC class containing CPU class, MB class, memory class, and etc...)
I think I must use Object.create() in definition of those member classes in the PC class... Is there any way to achieve this?